# Unable to mount D-drive of windows (Fast boot disabled in Windows)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a dual boot setup installed in disks as follows:

- 128GB SSD: Windows 10
- 1TB HDD: 150GB Partition for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS + Remaining as D drive in Windows

I have disabled the "Fast Startup" option in Windows 10, which supposedly causes problems for mounting the hard drive.

This is my disk partition structure:

```
varshith@ghost:$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                                  /snap/gtk-common
loop1  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-logs
loop2  squashf                                                  /snap/core/6350
loop3  squashf                                                  /snap/spotify/35
loop4  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-calc
loop5  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-3-26
loop6  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-char
loop7  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-syst
sda                                                             
├─sda1                                                          
├─sda2                                                          
├─sda3 vfat                9265-0C62                            /boot/efi
└─sda4 ext4                2a060833-af29-49fc-8a50-546aad2d7250 /
sdb                                                             
├─sdb1 vfat    ESP         3298-9385                            
├─sdb2                                                          
├─sdb3                                                          
├─sdb4 ntfs                2C1A6EFF1A6EC604                     
├─sdb5 ntfs    Image       A436EFCC36EF9D94                     
└─sdb6 ntfs    DELLSUPPORT 2CB0C81BB0C7EA02
```

Here sda2 is the partition I would like to mount. I don't know why is it not being recognized as an NTFS partition. Does the BitLocker encryption has anything to do with this?

[This is my disk structure as shown in Windows 10 Disk Management Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3MIR.png)

I have tried the following to get my D-drive part mounted on Ubuntu, and none of them were successful:

1. I expected the drive to appear in Devices(or Other Locations) in the
   Nautilus file explorer automatically. (It used to happen in
   Windows7-Ubuntu dual boot in my previous system, a few years ago.)
2. I tried to mount the disk manually:

```
varshith@ghost:/media$ sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda2 /media/DATA
[sudo] password for varshith: 
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?`
```

3. In Read-only mode (Note: ntfs-3g package is already installed):

```
varshith@ghost:/media$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda2 /media/DATA
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

4. I received a suggestion to run the check disk tool on that drive by logging into Windows OS. I did run the command CHKDSK on Windows Powershell which took more than an hour to complete. But again while trying to mount the disk, I'm getting the same error: `NTFS signature is missing`

Do note that I do not wish to format the sda2 partition since I have some required data and would like to just mount it to Ubuntu either in Read-Write mode or in Read-only mode.

Comment: Have you by any chance activated Dynamic Volumes in Windows? That's a Microsoft proprietary technology not supported in Linux.

Comment: You should run `lsblk -f` to show filesystem info.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia No, I have not activated Dynamic Volumes in Windows. Also please check the Windows Disk Management tool snapshot.

Comment: @mikewhatever I ran the `lsblk -f` command and have included the result in the question.

Comment: Is bitlocker enabled on the drive in question?

Comment: @vidarlo It looks like the BitLocker is enabled in the drive. I did not know anything about the BitLocker earlier. I will disable it, try to mount and then post an update. Thanks.

Comment: BitLocker being enabled was the problem. By disabling it, the drive was automatically mounted in Ubuntu. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the BitLocker being enabled for the disk in discussion. Disable the BitLocker encryption by going to:
Control Panel > System & Security > BitLocker Drive Encryption > Select - Turn Off BitLocker